# F.Promise exception handling

Tags: java, playframework, exception, promise

Assuming there is some method `foo` defined:

`F.Promise<T> foo() {
 // some implementation
}`

(`F.Promise` comes from Play Framework)

How should the caller handle `RuntimeException`'s which may be thrown after calling `foo`?
Using `try-catch` block? or should it be guaranteed by the author that any possible exception is **always** held inside the returned promise - so using `F.Promise.recover`?

Is it a good when these two approaches are mixed together or it should be avoided? What are the best practices concerning such issue?

Comment: Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: @marcospereira I am using Play 2.3.1